# Mysql in node.js (Java Script) Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, async-await

Regards
I'm trying with nodejs to make a loop to execute some queries and depending on if a record exists or not do one action or another (update or delete).

This is the function I have inside my class:
**CODE NUMBER 1**

```js
class BBDDP extends BBDD {
    insertOrUpdate = async (profile) => {
        let bdc = await this.connect();
        await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await profile.tweets.forEach(async tweet => {
                await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    bdc.query(
                        ("SELECT x FROM table_x WHERE id = ?"), [profile.id],
                        function (err, row) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            } else {
                                if (row && row.length) {
                                    //bdc.connect()
                                    bdc.query("DELETE * FROM table_x where id = ?";[profile.id])
                                    console.log('Case row was found!');
                                } else {
                                    bdc.query("INSERT INTO table_x set name = ?, addres = ? where id = ?;",[profile.name, profile.addres, profile.id])
                                    console.log('No case row was found :( !');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    resolve();
                })
                resolve();
            });
        });
        bdc.end()
    }
}
```

My BBDDC class inherits from another class called BBDD which basically has only 3 basic methods that can be used to run.
**CODE NUMBER 2**

Class BBDD:

```
class BBDD {
    /**
     * Clase helper que se usa para poder hacer query contra la bbdd.
     * @param {*} ip Direccion ip del servidor
     * @param {*} user Usuario para la autenticación 
     * @param {*} password La contraseña para la bbdd
     * @param {*} dataBase Nombre de la base de datos
     * @param {*} port El puerto
     */

    constructor(ip, user, password, dataBase, port = 3306) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.dataBase = dataBase;
        this.port = port;
        this.data = null;
        console.log(`Info de conexion con la bbdd ip ${this.ip} en el puerto ${this.port}, a la bbdd ${this.dataBase}.`);
    }

    connect = async () => {
        let con = await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            this.con = mysql.createConnection({
                host: this.ip,
                user: this.user,
                password: this.password,
                database: this.dataBase,
                port: this.port,
                charset: "utf8"
            });

            this.con.connect(function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Connected!");
            });
            resolve(this.con);
            return this.con;
        });
        return con;
    }

    query = async (query, values = null) => {
        /**
         * @param {*} query Query, es la consulta que se desea ejecutar.
         * @returns La respuesta de mysql
         */
        await this.connect();
        return await new Promise(async resolve => {
            if (values != null) {
                let x = this.con.query(query, values, function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    resolve(results);
                })
                await this.closeConnection();
            } else {

                let x = this.con.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    resolve(results);
                })
                await this.closeConnection();
            }
        });
    }

    closeConnection = async () => {
        return await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            this.con.end();
            console.log("Conexion cerrada.")
            resolve();
        })
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is, in the same loop inside the callback of the mysql query function what I want to do is the query to know if it exists or not and depending on that inside the same callback execute one query or another, but I don't know why before executing the queries inside the callback the connection is closed and I get the following failure:

`Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.`

This failure occurs when I call the function called closeConnection at the end of the loop that executes in the insertOrUpdate function.

The execution is from my main class:

```
class Main {
    constructor() {
    }

    static async run() {
        this.api = MyApi('xxx', "xxx","xxx");
        this.bdCargas = new BBDDQ("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        this.bd = new BBDDP("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        let profiles = await this.bdCargas.getQueue();

        profiles.forEach(async profile => {
            await this.api.setFollowers(profile);
            await this.api.setUserContents(profile);
            await this.bd.insertOrUpdate(profile);
        })
    }
}
```

I have tried, in making the functions asynchronous, changing classes from static to non-static. Also to run with different structure, etc... Nothing works for me.

I want something like this:

```
insertOrUpdate = async (profile) => {
  await this.conect();
  profile.tweets.forEach(async tweet => {
                await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    bdc.query(
                        ("SELECT x FROM table_x WHERE id = ?"), [profile.id],
                        function (err, row) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            } else {
                                if (row && row.length) {
                                    //bdc.connect()
                                    bdc.query("DELETE * FROM table_x where id = ?";[profile.id])
                                    console.log('Case row was found!');
                                } else {
                                    bdc.query("INSERT INTO table_x set name = ?, addres = ? where id = ?;",[profile.name, profile.addres, profile.id])
                                    console.log('No case row was found :( !');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    resolve();
                })
                resolve();
            });
this.closeConnection();
}
```

To be able to execute a loop and to be able to do the necessary actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.
My failure is due to the forEach I use, as it doesn't wait for promises, the solution was to change it to the modern js forEach.

```
insertOrUpdate = async (profile) => {
  await this.conect();
  for(let tweet of profile.tweets){
                await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    bdc.query(
                        ("SELECT x FROM table_x WHERE id = ?"), [profile.id],
                        function (err, row) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            } else {
                                if (row && row.length) {
                                    //bdc.connect()
                                    bdc.query("DELETE * FROM table_x where id = ?";[profile.id])
                                    console.log('Case row was found!');
                                } else {
                                    bdc.query("INSERT INTO table_x set name = ?, addres = ? where id = ?;",[profile.name, profile.addres, profile.id])
                                    console.log('No case row was found :( !');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    resolve();
                })
                resolve();
        }
  this.closeConnection();
}
```